# Emmet HTML div tag with multiple words class name

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, emmet

I did not find the answer on documentation for this question.

As we know, div.container gives

```
<div class="container">
```

However, what abbreviation shall be used for

```
<div class="row placeholders">
```

Anyone knows? Thanks.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

From the [Emmet Cheat Sheet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/):

> ```html
> p.class1.class2.class3
>     <p class="class1 class2 class3"></p>
> ```

So, `div.row.placeholders` will give you:

```html
<div class="row placeholders"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, MattDMo. I haven't found solution for multiple attributes. How about the shortcut for this one?  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="id_username" maxlength="254" name="username" type="text" required autofocus=""/>

Comment: @day the link I provided gives details on all of Emmet's capabilities. Look at the "Custom Attributes" section.